# What is the safe way of get the return status from an executed shell command in c++

Tags: c++, centos7, c++17

Since the function `std::system(const char* command)` from `cstdlib` [doesn't guarantee that will return the correct return status from the shell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/#return), then how can I run a command in shell using c/c++ and have a guarantee that will give me the right return value?

In my case, for example, I ran a command with:

```
bool is_process_running(std::string p_name){
  std::string command_str= "ps aux | grep '" + p_name + "' | egrep -v '(grep|bash)'";

  int result(0);
  result= system(command_str.c_str());

  return result == 0;
}
```

If I run, for example, `ps aux | grep 'my_process' | egrep -v '(grep|bash)'` directly into the terminal and after that `echo $?`, I see it returning `0` because `my_process` is running and also returning `1` when I use a non running process. But, the code above returns a different value. This code used to work when I tested in CentOs 6 but now in CentOs 7 doesn't work anymore. So, what can I use to run the shell command and get the correct result?

I also found a solution using `pidof` command but I can't use this because pidof doesn't consider the parameters passed to `my_process` which I need since I have many instances of this process each with different arguments.

Comment: What shell are you using? If you want guarancy, run `popen` 3 times for each process `ps`, `grep` and `egrep` with pipes between them.

Comment: It's better to use `pgrep my_process` to check if a process named my_process is running. Using `ps | grep` pipe will may give you false positives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a command and get return code stdout and stderr of command in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164723/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-return-code-stdout-and-stderr-of-command-in-c)

Comment: If you want to understand how something works, you need to cut through the layers of abstraction.  You can implement this using `fork`, `pipe`, and `exec`.

Comment: Oof, that function gives me tingles. Be _very very careful_ about what you allow to pass into `is_process_running`. You'd be better off taking some non-shell approach: does your OS not provide an API for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [the exit status of Bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#EXIT_STATUS) isn't guaranteed to be the exit status of the last executed command. If there's an error in the command you pass, you can't really distinguish it from `egrep` failing to match anything.

What you need to do is to do is to both get the exit status *and* parse the output (both to standard output and standard error). This can be accomplished by copying much of what the `system` function does: First [create a pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) for the output (both `stderr` and `stdout` could be using the same pipe), then [fork a new process](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to run the shell, and then [execute the shell and the pipeline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).

In the parent process you [wait for the child to exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), and get its exit status. If it's zero then you know everything worked fine, and you can discard all the output from the pipe. If it's non-zero you have to read the output from the pipe to see what happened, if there was some error except `egrep` failing.

Comment: @Fabiotk There are several thousands of examples on how to use these functions, all over the Internet (and quite a few of them here on this site). Please do some searching first.